# Qt app: To detect hotpluggable USB Keyboard and Mouse

Tags: linux, qt, embedded, busybox, udev

I am developing a Qt application that runs on Embedded Linux (on i.Mx6 Platform). My application should work with the input devices: USB Keyboard, USB Mouse and Touchscreen(default). My device uses mdev utility to configure the input devices and my **/etc/mdev.conf** looks like this:

```
event[0-9]* root:root 660 >input/
```

Everything is working fine, if I connect all the input devices to my target on bootup. And the order of the eventIDs Linux kernel is allotting to the input devices are as below:

```
/dev/input/event0         - USB Keyboard.
/dev/input/event1         - USB Mouse.
/dev/input/event2         - Touch Screen.
```

But these Ids are dynamically assigned by the kernel, and I want to implement a way to set these devices to have fixed ID all the time whether the devices are all connected on bootup, or after bootup. I read about this online, and all folks suggested me to `use udev and set Symlinks` to the devices.

I am pretty new to Linux, and I feel our system uses **mdev** for device management. Can I achieve what I need using mdev utility, any help on this is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/plain/docs/mdev.txt).

Comment: I have seen this documentation. My doubt is about how to change this `/etc/mdev.conf` file so that `event0` will always get `keyboard` (for example) do I need to set it based on `vendor & product id` of the device ?.

Comment: As of now I did a work around to `grep` the `dmesg` log as below: `KBD=/dev/input/$(dmesg | grep -i "Keyboard as"  | grep -o input[0-9] | sed s/input/event/)` and using this varaible while launching my Qt application. But, I know this is not right approach. I still have to figure out how do it more effectively.

Comment: Apparently, mdev does not support USB vendor/product IDs directly; you have to do this in a script called from mdev.